# Livecharts not displaying Label on x axis in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, livecharts

I am displaying data in my livecharts and Label values are binded (visible in debugging). But somehow in the UI, it is showing one or two values instead of all the values in string array from the backend.

Model.cs Code:

```
private string[] _Labels;
public string[] Labels
{
    get
    {
        return _Labels;
    }
    set
    {
        SetProperty(ref _Labels, value);
    }
}
```

ModelViewCode.cs

```
Labels = new[] {"Maria", "Susan", "Charles", "Frida"};
```

XAML:

```
<lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
    <lvc:Axis Labels="{Binding Labels}">
    </lvc:Axis>
</lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
```

Screenshot

[image: Image of the Output]

Comment: Did you checked the Livecharts demos? Also check if Labels are not overlapping, so try adding separators.

Comment: Thanks, this helped.

Answer (score 4):

Define an AxisSeparator for your axis like this, and set its `Step` property to `1`

```
<lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
    <lvc:AxesCollection>
        <lvc:Axis Labels="{Binding Labels}">
            <lvc:Axis.Separator>
                <lvc:Separator Step="1" />
            </lvc:Axis.Separator>
        </lvc:Axis>
    </lvc:AxesCollection>
</lvc:CartesianChart.AxisX>
```

Comment: Wow, that wasn't very intuitive to me. Your proposed solution works perfectly well, showing all the labels.